# UFW allow SSH on non-standard port to IPv6 addresses

Tags: ipv6, ufw

I want to open my UFW firewall to SSH on port 1234 while denying access to all through port 22. My LAN DNS is resolving to IPv6 addresses and I don't want to change that.

I'm having trouble forming the IPv6 net mask in order to specify my LAN hosts in IPv6

Here's what I'm trying:

ufw deny 22
ufw allow from 10.0.0.0/24 to any port 1234

All good so far, but now for IPv6

```
ufw allow from 2222:3333:aaaa:bbbb/64 to any port 2314
```

gives

```
Bad Source Address
```

Comment: Try adding `::` before `/64`, like this: `2222:3333:aaaa:bbbb::/64`.

Comment: Right. Of course.Just like we fill in the IPv4 address with zeros.`10.0.0.0/24' We need a correctly formed address. The :: will fill in the zeros. Thanks.